# Download file method in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

When i tried the below code, i have received  "operator does not exist: integer =@ integer" and ArgumentException.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue pls?

```
public FileContentResult GetFile(int fileid)
{
     NpgsqlDataReader rdr;
     byte[] fileContent = null;
     string mimeType=" ";
     string fileName=" "; 
    NpgsqlConnection conn = new       NpgsqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["portalconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
using (portalconnectionstring ps = new portalconnectionstring())
{
    var query = "select filename,content_type,filedata from tblfiles where     fileid='"+fileid+"'";
  var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileid", fileid);
  conn.Open();
  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  if (rdr.HasRows)
  {
     rdr.Read();
     fileContent=(byte[]) rdr["filedata"];
     mimeType = rdr["content_type"].ToString();
    fileName = rdr["filename"].ToString()
  }
 }
conn.Close();
return File(fileContent, mimeType, fileName);
}
```

Comment: in this line `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileid", fileid);` where did `fileid` came from what is his value and type ?

Comment: Hi, i just updated the above code. Actually we need to pass fileid as parameter in the function itself. The problem was in my route path. Now it is working fine. while running appliation i  used below path http://localhost:626829/Fileupload/GetFile?fileid=1 and got the solution